# Can't execute Python script from Motioneye (on Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, motion-detection

I've installed the last version of Motioneye on my Raspberry Pi 3 (with Raspbian). All works correctly: Web-Gui, streaming and saving snapshot and video with the options "Still image"/"Movies". 
But I want also to execute a Python script when motion is detected. The function "Run a Command" (with the path of my script, "/home/myName/Desktop/script.py" unfortunatly doesn't work. 
I've tried to call "chmod +x" on the script file, but is the same. 
How can I resolve?

PS: Obviously, the Python script is correct and if I start from Python IDLE (or bash) it works!

[image: "Run a Command"]

Comment: Just a guess, try to put "<full-path-to-python> <full-path-to-script>" in.

Comment: I've tried, but It doesn't work (also modifying manually the file motion.conf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
It was necessary to install an older version of Raspbian (May, 2016). Now everything works. Probably some update was incompatible with motioneye ...